# Solidity: function consuming too much gas

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, dapps

I am developing a todo list dapp. Currently I have the `createTask` `toggleCompleted` and now I need the `deleteTask` to be done.

The smart contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract TodoList {

  uint public taskCount = 0;

  mapping(uint => Task) public tasks;

  struct Task {
    uint id;
    string content;
    bool completed;
  }

  event TaskCreated(
    uint id,
    string content,
    bool completed
  );

  event TaskDeleted(
    uint id,
    string content,
    bool completed
  );

  event TaskCompleted(
    uint id,
    bool completed
  );

  constructor() public {
    createTask("Check out dappuniversity.com");
  }

  function createTask(string memory _content) public {
    taskCount ++;
    tasks[taskCount] = Task(taskCount, _content, false);
    emit TaskCreated(taskCount, _content, false);
  }

  function toggleCompleted(uint _id) public {
    Task memory _task = tasks[_id];
    _task.completed = !_task.completed;
    tasks[_id] = _task;
    emit TaskCompleted(_id, _task.completed);
  }

  function deleteTask(uint _id) public {
    Task memory _task = tasks[_id];
    delete tasks[_id];
    emit TaskDeleted(_id, _task.content, _task.completed);
  }

}
```

When I call the `deteleTask` MetaMask says that there `Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.`. I have noticed that for `createTask` there is a gas consumption of `0.00222456ETH` and for deleting `0.12771752ETH` the difference is significant, and it does not depend on the function body because I have make them equal. On what does it depend and how do I reduce the gas for this transaction? Do I have to add something to the `truffle-config.js`?

truffle-config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
    }
  },
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200
    }
  }
}
```

Ganache settings.

```
GAS PRICE
20000000000

GAS LIMIT
6721975
```

UPDATE I have switched to the harmony one testnet, the same issues persists. Empty deleteTask function requires to pay 0.76 harmony and metamask says the following

```
This transaction is expected to fail. Trying to execute it is expected to be expensive but fail, and is not recommended.
```

Comment: How are you going to get the tasks list in Dapp?

Comment: @MadJackal using react.js

Comment: 1. There is no view method in your contract for getting a list of tasks. 2. You cannot get a mapping list in Solidity - only array.

Comment: @MadJackal I need the delete method to work, everything else works just fine. The problem is within the gas fee.

Comment: Try not to use the local ```_task``` variable, but do an ```emit``` before ```delete```. Or try replacing ```delete tasks[_id];``` with ```tasks[_id].id=0;```.

Comment: @Brat The code seems fine. Which solc version are you using? Is a private test network or a public one? Are you sure you are using the correct address and abi?

Comment: for ethereum chain I was using ganache on localhost, now on harmony the testnet. I am not using solc, should I? I compile code using `truffle compile`

Comment: @Brat I tried your contract with solc 0.8 in Remix, creation costs 77813 gas, and deletion costs 30488, so the contract work fine. If there's a problem perhaps it is in the environment used. Usually solc uses opcodes from the latest available Ethereum fork and it might not be fully compatible with other EVMs.

Answer (score 2):

The cause for the gas consumption might be connected to the error message. Before Solidity 0.8.0 if a contract fails because of an `assert` it uses an invalid opcode and therefore it uses up all remaining gas. So if you set a high gas limit it will eat up all the gas. If a contract fails because of a `revert` no additional gas will be used up. More info on this can be found here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=assert#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require.

Edit:
For further investigation could you post the following information:

- the output of `solc --version`
- The methods and parameters that you call in your transactions (e.g. how do you create the task struct)

Edit 2:
I was testing your contract on https://remix.ethereum.org/ and everything seems to work. Do you only see errors on bsc related networks or also on remix?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a mapping basically sets all elements of the struct to the default value. That could have been the issue.

I made some small changes, by basically adding a bool that indicates if a task still exists.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract TodoList {

  uint public taskCount = 0;

  mapping(uint => Task) public tasks;

  struct Task {
    uint id;
    string content;
    bool completed;
    bool exists;
  }

  event TaskCreated(
    uint id,
    string content,
    bool completed
  );

  event TaskDeleted(
    uint id,
    string content,
    bool completed
  );

  event TaskCompleted(
    uint id,
    bool completed
  );

  constructor() {
    createTask("Check out dappuniversity.com");
  }

  function createTask(string memory _content) public {
    taskCount ++;
    tasks[taskCount] = Task(taskCount, _content, false, true);
    emit TaskCreated(taskCount, _content, false);
  }

  function toggleCompleted(uint _id) public {
    require(tasks[_id].exists, "Task does not exist");
    tasks[_id].completed = !tasks[_id].completed;
    emit TaskCompleted(_id, tasks[_id].completed);
  }

  function deleteTask(uint _id) public {
    require(tasks[_id].exists, "Task does not exist");
    tasks[_id].exists = false;
    emit TaskDeleted(_id, tasks[_id].content,tasks[_id].completed);
  }
}
```

Does this solve the gas topic?

If not, the source of the problem might be outside of the contract: How do you initiate the transaction, in JS?
Which function is calling the web3 wrappers and which one is calculating the gas (do you leave it up to MetaMask?)